# Honda Accord 2010: Why does my alarm go off every time i open the door and my door controls don't work?

Tags: honda, accord, locks, door, alarm

I just had some body work done on the car, and because they had to take out one of the headlights, I had to enter a code to get control of the radio and cd player again. Everything else was just fine though.

However, for some reason now EVERY time I open ANY of the doors, the car alarm goes off, and none of the door controls work (the windows, the lock/unlock, the side mirror adjustors).

Other than that, the car drives just fine, what's going on here? Do Honda accords have a lockdown mode? Is this a shit battery?

Comment: Sounds like you need to take it back to whomever worked on it and have them fix it. Wasn't like that before the repair, shouldn't be like that after.

Comment: Maybe the blew a fuse or something? No clue just a guess

Comment: thanks for the recommendations, going to the body shop tomorrow to ask them to fix it right away, otherwise im going to have to read the Honda 2010 repair manual and remove the alarm system myself in the mean time. These silly repetitive stressors of modern society...

Comment: Just to let everyone know, i took it to the auto body shop, and the guy used a wedge tool to lift up the plastic panel with all the window controls and locks. There was an electrical wire that was loose and popped out from the rest of the controls. All you gotta do is plug it back in, and the alarm, locks, and window controls will all work fine again.